# How to find out "number of tablet servers running" in accumulo?

Tags: accumulo

1. Im trying to find out number of tablets servers. Any command to get so.
2. what does accumulo/tables/!0 contain ? Is it possible to view the data insisde !0 ?

Answer (score 2):

1. The monitor will show you this (like was said in the other answer). `connector.instanceOperations().getTabletServers().size()` will also provide programmatic access to the number of TServers. See the [Connector](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Connector.html) and [InstanceOperations](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/admin/InstanceOperations.html) javadoc.
2. "/accumulo/tables/!0" contains the data for the "accumulo.metadata" (or "!METADATA" if you're using an older version) table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Accumulo HTTP Monitor page.  It can generally be found on port 50095

https://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/accumulo_user_manual.html